# What can I use on OS-X to open a .bm2 file

Tags: macos, mac

Firstly - what is a .bm2 file - and how can I convert/open it on OS-X?

This appears to be a type of bitmap file (from looking at it) but a search of the web does not yield terribly useful information. I know the content of this file is several images with comments (at least).

Comment: Where did you get/find the file?

Comment: What is the output of `file yourfilename.bm2`? (Run from the terminal). See [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) for more information on the command.

Answer (score 0):

BM2 usually belongs to a game called SubSpace/Continuum or to BoardMaker which is a PCB design program.
Subspace has an OSX version.
Boardmaker I  have no idea.

In some cases it is just a BMP with an incorrect extension.
In that case a rename will allow Preview to open it.
Give that a try. It certainly can't hurt.